# How to configure a Spring InboundChannelAdapter for Spring XD?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have a custom Spring XD source that I want to use:

```
   package com.my.springproject;

   import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
   import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;

   public class MySource
   {
       @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "output", 
           poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
       public String next() {
           return "foo";
       }
   }
```

The question now is, how do I register this in my ModuleConfiguration.java, so that Spring XD will recognize it as a valid source? So far I have this, but the Source never logs anything.

My ModuleConfiguration looks like this:

```
package com.my.springproject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan( value = { "com.my.springproject" } )
public class ModuleConfiguration {
   @Bean
   MessageChannel output() {
      return new DirectChannel();
   }

      @Bean
   MySource source() {
      return new MySource();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark your `MySource` with the `@MessageEndpoint`, or just with the `@Component`.

Looks like we overdid there a bit and have this logic in the `MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor`:

```
    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanClass, Component.class) == null) {
        // we only post-process stereotype components
        return bean;
    }
```

Looks like this is a bit weird do not scan Messaging Annotations on just `@Bean`.

Feel free to raise a JIRA(https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue on the matter!